# SQL condition on at least one value of list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, implemented by Mysql.

`Users` table is like below:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jacks |
| 2 | Sanaz |

`UserInterests` table is like below:

| User_ID | Interest |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sport |
| 1 | Music |
| 1 | Movie |
| 2 | Music |
| 2 | Football |

And, on the search query side I have an array list like:

```
$interests = ['Music', 'Science', 'Computer'];
```

In what ways can I implement a query to return a row whose interest column contains **at least** one element of `$interests`?

For example, by considering the mentioned values in tables and array the query should return the Jacks' record.

Comment: Provide your array as JSON array and use `MEMBER OF` operator. Or concatenate to CSV and use `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `IN` operator inside a `WHERE` clause, then use the `LIMIT` clause to limit the amount of returned rows:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM       Users u
INNER JOIN UsersInterests ui
        ON u.ID = ui.User_ID 
       AND ui.Interest IN ('Music', 'Science', 'Computer')
LIMIT 1
```

whereas `('Music', 'Science', 'Computer')` can be passed as input using your variable `$interests`.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mTaQbsHqqYcybg9khm2K8R/0).